# How to use bitcoind with CUDA-ready box?

Tags: bitcoind, gpu, nodes

I am not asking for mining (which is all the information I could find on the net). I am asking for the regular bitcoind daemon, looking for having a full node with a reasonable high performance per watt.

My use case is: I have a [Jetson TK1 board](https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1) and would like to use it. However, I have seen that bitcoind tends to saturate the CPU and I would prefer to take advantage of the CUDA cores (both for performance and for energy consumption).

My google-fu is weak, and there is a lot of information about mining (which I am not interested in) but not on this specific application.

I was considering performing a fork of the [bitcoin source at GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/), but it seems a huge task and I am not sure if the community will be as interested as I am. And maybe there are efforts on it, which I could not find.

Comment: +1 for not trying to mine with it. It would seem to me that some of the hairy bits of the bitcoind source code would need to be rewritten/optimized to specifically take advantage of your CUDA setup, I don't think it will do that out of the box and I have no idea how good a job a special CUDA compiler would do. If you are willing to do that work, you might want to ask on IRC #bitcoin-wizards or on the bitcoin development mailing list whether there's interest in such a thing with any chance of getting it merged upstream. They might warn you for pitfalls or just tell you it's not worth it.

Comment: You could probably move signature verification to a GPU if you felt like it, but keep in mind that signature verification is consensus critical. Any implementation error in this sort of code could result in thefts, especially if the code is used on any sort of scale.